# Azure AppService continuous deployment from container registry tag selection

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I have an AppService which uses Azure Container Registry.
The docker images are built by the pipeline and pushed with a 'Docker push' task in Azure Release.
I am using semantic versioning, I put the version into the BuildNumber and to the image name.

[image]

I can see my images being available in the DeploymentCenter, along with all the tags that have been pushed so far.

[image]

However, whenever I create a Release in AZ DevOps, it does not automatically get deployed to the AppService.
I have to go to the DeploymentCenter, pick the newest tag and then redeploy again (*restarting the app didn't seem to work, but am no 100% sure*).

In any case, **I would like the AppService to be updated and run the latest image automatically when the release succeeds in DevOps.**
Is that possible with the `Docker push` task to ACR?

Also, I wonder - I have the 'Include latest tag' tickbox checked, but the 'latest' tag is not available in the tag dropdown in Deployment Center. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that possible with the Docker push task to ACR?

Of course, yes. But the thing you need to know is the continuous deployment of the App Service only triggers for the one tag can it can't change. Generally, we use the certain tag `latest`. So you need to create the image with the tag `latest` all the time, don't use the default tag `$(Build.BuildId)` in DevOps.

> I have the 'Include latest tag' tickbox checked, but the 'latest' tag
> is not available in the tag dropdown in Deployment Center. Why is
> that?

I'm not familiar with DevOps, but I think the `include latest tag` means the latest `Build.BuildId`, not one certain tag, so it will change each time when you create the image and push it. And it won't work for App Service Continuous Deployment.

Comment: Thanks - that sounds a bit weird and seems against the good practice of image tagging...

Comment: @Bartosz But for App Service, that's it.

Comment: @Bartosz Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I have no updates, thanks. I have upvoted your answer, and in case nobody comes with a better idea, I will accept it as 'the answer'.

Comment: @Bartosz OK, I'm glad to help you if you have more questions about this issue.

Comment: @Bartosz Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: So does it work differently if I use some custom tag like DockerImageName:ExampleTag than if I use DockerImageName:latest? Currenlty if I wan't to update my app service I need to delete it and redeploy it by bicep. Even if I restart app service it will not take updated image.

Comment: I noticed that if I update image with same tag and then stop and start app service it will load new image. Documentation says that restart would need but I noticed it didn't. Here is link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-containers-03